# AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() returns empty array since in iOS 16 beta

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

Since iOS 16 beta the following code always returns an empty array:

```
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
```

It is working fine in all other versions. I'm not noticing any API change in the documentation so I'm not sure how to fix this one.